# How to retrieve a set of documents from Cosmos Db from a set of IDs

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am looking to retrieve the items from my Cosmos Db collection and I have a list of Ids which I want to retrieve. all code are running in an Azure Function and below is the code where I get all Ids in List **filteredResult** where I get list of all Ids. I am looking the best way to complete this code to retrieve all items from my Cosmos Db  collection considering 30-40 Ids at a time.

```
 public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("testSB", "SubscriberName", Connection = "AzureServiceBusString")] string mySbMsg,
        [CosmosDB(
    databaseName: "DBName",
    collectionName: "CollectionName",
    ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")] DocumentClient client,
        ILogger log)
    {
        
        try {
             log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");


            
            var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            jsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
            List<MyItem> lists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyItem>>(mySbMsg, jsonSerializerSettings);
            List<string> filteredResult = (from s in lists
                                          where s.DocType == "TEST"
                                 select s.Id).ToList();

        }
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand completely but... aside from id, do you know the partition key's value for each of the documents you're retrieving? Also: knowing the id, you have two options: discrete reads (one per id), or a query (where you can then check each document's id against an array of known id's). You'll need to evaluate which method works best for you, and performance will be impacted by usage of partition key (without partition key value, you'll end up doing partition-scanning).

Comment: well for now we have the default partition key and that is ID itself. and I will be checking the ID of the document from the list of 30 IDs I have. So in Query term in Cosmos DB it will be like this> (SELECT * FROM Tble where id is in(list of IDs I get))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has recently been covered under [Microsoft Q&A forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/129094/how-to-retrieve-a-set-of-documents-from-cosmos-db.html). ***Posting the answer here again for broader reach.***

This code can be used after you created the 'filteredResult' (just replace the 'input' list with 'filteredResult')

```
 List<string> input = new List<string>();
             input.Add("1");
             input.Add("2");
             input.Add("3");                
              var option = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };               
              IQueryable<Family> queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("families", "items").ToString(), "SELECT * FROM books where books.id IN " + "('" + string.Join( "','", input) + "')",option);
              List<Family> posts = queryable.ToList();
              Console.WriteLine("Read count = {0}", posts.Count);
```

Also notice I created a model class for document properties as below:

```
 public class Family
 {
     public int id;
     public string city;
 }
```